# Javascript recursive permutation generator

Tags: javascript, recursion, permutation

I'm trying to implement a recursive permutation generator in Javascript, but I can't seem to get it to go through all the recursion branches (see the Results below).

I know I'm missing something important, can someone help me understand where I've gone wrong?

```
    var permute = function(input){
        var permutation = function (arr, position){
            if(position >= arr.length-1){
                results.push(arr);
            }else{
                var tempSwap="";
                for(i=position;i<arr.length;i++){
                    tempSwap = arr[position];
                    arr.splice(position,1,arr[i]);
                    arr.splice(i,1,tempSwap);
                    permutation(arr,(position+1));
            }
            return;
        }
    };

    permutation(input,0);
};

var results=[];
permute(['a','b','c']);
console.log(results);
```

**Results:**
[ [ 'a', 'c', 'b' ], [ 'a', 'c', 'b' ] ]

Comment: What do you expect the results to be?

Comment: You're always acting on the same `input` array. You will need to create some copies!

Comment: its only going through 2 of 3 elements because of your arr.length-1. Your arrays length is 3. 3 minus 1 is 2.

Comment: You should use simple assignments instead of those `splice` calls. They're equivalent to `arr[position] = arr[i]; arr[i] = tempSwap;`

Comment: Thanks Bergi, I used this cleaner assignment in my final code too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two errors: you was working on the same array without making copies and your loop counter `i` was a global variable. Fixed code:

```
 var permute = function(input){
        var permutation = function (arr, position){
            if(position == arr.length-1){ // >= was redundant and confusing
                results.push(arr);
            }else{
                for(var i=position;i<arr.length;i++){ // use local i
                    var tempSwap = arr[position];
                    arr.splice(position,1,arr[i]);
                    arr.splice(i,1,tempSwap);
                    permutation(arr.slice(),(position+1)); // you need a copy here
            }
            return;
        }
    };

    permutation(input,0);
};

var results=[];
permute(['a','b','c']);
console.log(results.join(' ')); // a,b,c a,c,b b,a,c b,c,a c,a,b c,b,a
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sagqkchL/1/

Not making copies caused all of your result arrays to look the same. The global variable caused only 2 results being produced.

Comment: Thanks! I've been banging my head against this one forever, it was variable scoping!

Answer (score 0):

> I know I'm missing important

Your `i` variable is [implictly global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Declare it with `var`, and your basic problem will go away.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you are not copying the `input` array so you're always modifying the same object (and end up with `result[0] == result[1] == …`); you end your recursion one level too early (the base case is when you've met the end, not before); and also you should create the `results` array within the `permute` function.

```
function permute(input){
    function permutation(arr, position){
        if(position >= arr.length) {
            results.push(arr);
        } else {
            permutation(arr, position+1); // nothing is swapped, no need to copy anything
                                          // you can also omit this line and start i=position
            for (var i=position+1; i<arr.length; i++) {
                var tmp = arr.slice();
                tmp[position] = arr[i];
                tmp[i] = arr[position];
                permutation(tmp, position+1);
            }
        }
    };
    var results = [];
    permutation(input, 0);
    return results;
};

console.log(permute(['a','b','c'])); // [["a","b","c"],["a","c","b"],["b","a","c"],["b","c","a"],["c","b","a"],["c","a","b"]]
```